# How will Canada customs treat shipped luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, mail, backpacking

We’re Canadians backpacking abroad for 6 months. We brought well-used camping gear over with us that we purchased in Canada years ago (we no longer have receipts). It’s halfway through our trip and we want to mail the camping gear home now (from Europe) so we can stop lugging it around. Are we likely to be charged customs fees for our gear even though we purchased it at home? If so what’s the best way to avoid that?

Comment: Yes it’s likely (you won’t be able to ship it without a customs form and that should trigger import taxes). Exemptions for personal items are usually linked to you carrying them with you through the border, or when moving. You could put a very low value on the customs form, but if they don’t agree with it it may turn out quite nasty (I.e. they would tax on their estimate and possibly add penalties on top). Probably depends how obvious it is that the items indeed have a very low value.

Comment: @jcaron You could still benefit from the personal exemption (as if you bought them outside Canada) when mailing goods from abroad. Duties and taxes are assessed on the mail but refundable upon declaration on arriving in Canada.

Comment: To be honest, customs is not the only problem, whether you technically qualify for a relief or not, I find that getting the shipping company to declare it properly is often a struggle as well. For small parcels and individuals (I assume they treat corporate clients differently), they don't want to bother with the details and are happy to just collect some taxes that may or may not actually be owed and slap their fees on top, even if you put something else on the form. Getting that rectified after the fact is a pain.

Comment: @xngtng I believe most other countries don’t allow that (in the case of regular short term travel and not when moving to the country). Do you have a link explaining the procedure for this in Canada?

Comment: Without original receipts it would be difficult. You can ask for a ATA carnet and declare every single item (which probably you should make anyway to send the package). You must have stamped the carnet on return so you have not to pay taxes. But check: maybe paying import duties (and possibly twice) may be cheaper. (ATA carnet have a base fee).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi [ATA Carnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Carnet) would only be useful for [new] goods bought in Canada and being temporary admitted to Europe and being brought back to Canada. In most cases used goods (often used at least for 6 months) are not of great interest for customs. In this case they are *well-used* accourding to the OP, which the trained customs official will see.

Comment: @jcaron Apparently it used to be explicitly allowed: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/import/courier/menu-eng.html; https://publications.gc.ca/collections/collection_2009/asfc-cbsa/PS38-15-2008E.pdf. But the newest form (from 2016) uses the wording "goods to follow" instead of unaccompanied goods although the Tariff heading did not change. So I am actually not sure now if goods arriving before arrival can be claimed anymore. (1/2)

Comment: @jcaron If the goods arrive after the return it is certainly still possible (I probably should ask a new question about this change). It probably requires some planning coordination (perhaps choosing the slowest postal service available; having a reliable person to receive the goods and keep all the necessary forms etc.).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Here is a good example where a [ATA Carnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_Carnet) should have been used (but was not): [2022-09-05: Welsh charity cyclists in Spain get £7k bike customs charge - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-wales-62799594.amp). This situation would have been avoided with a Carnet. Expensive sportsgear and the equipment for music groups on tour in other customs areas are a common usage of Carnets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the 'gear' has any product type and/or numbers, a customs service can determin in which country it was sold (if they want to).

So be truthful and declare them 'as canadian bought between 20?? and 20?? for an estimated amount of CND ??? (see list inside)'.

Add list of product name, type, number and price.

If you have any documents on how they were transported to Europe, add/include a copy of that too.

Upon entry into Canada they should be also be declared as used goods, bought in canada, and sent back per post (with receipt and a copy of the list).

Comment: Thank you everyone who commented. I think this solution would have worked, but between the hassle, shipping costs and age of the gear, we decided to just leave it behind. In hindsight it seems like the ATA Carnet would have been ideal